# Изменить цвет ячеек, что повторяються в столбце

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

нужно изменить цвет ячеек, имеющих дубликаты в столбце, также добавить границы для всех ячеек и заменить жирный цвет названий столбцов на простой.
[image: входные файлы]

Желаемый результат:

[image: Результат:]

Много искал, не могу найти хорошей реализации. Буду благодарен за любую помощь)

Пример данных:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
'Tag': ["112-VAXV-0010","WATER_BALLAST_VALVE_SYSTEM","112-VAXV-0010",
         "WTR_BALL_HEADER","RELIEF","RELIEF","METERING"],
'Meta Name':["SBM Function - Ballast System",
             "SBM Function - Water Ballast Valve System",
             "SBM Function - On/Off Valve",
             "WTR_BALL_HEADER",
             "SBM Function - Relief (Thermal Or Pressure)",
             "SBM Function - Non-Return","SBM Function - Metering"]})
```

Comment: Вам нужно в выводе самой `Pandas` такое видеть или в `Excel`? Если второе, то не всё туда переносится. Вот это почитайте: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: @CrazyElf , в excel

Comment: Ну почитайте всё-таки ссылку. А так если в эксель, то и библиотеку надо брать, которая именно для экселя и работать с ней.

Comment: с остальным разобрался, только не могу сделать для каждой ячейки границы, как в экселе "All borders". Если кто знает как это сделать буду очень благодарен